# Primeface Conditional Confirmation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

## Problem

I have a simple form containing text and date input fields (both are mandatory) and a submit button.
What I want to do is trigger a confirmation dialog if the value in the text box meets certain criteria.

Without the ajax element on the `inputText` and `disabled` attributed on the `confirm` element it works fine but I obviously get a confirm dialog every time.

As soon as I add in the ajax on the inputText it only works second time.   ie. the first time I press the button nothing happens but then it works if I press the button a second time.

I guess this is because the inputText ajax updates the button and it becomes chicken and egg as without the update, the confirm dialog disabled attribute won't change.

What is the correct way to do this so that in this example the confirm dialog only shows in the input is ABC?   The actual logic is comparing the value to a list that is populated in the `PostConstruct` so I can't just use a letteral in the EL

## Code

I have boiled this down to

```
<p:messages id="msgs" showDetail="true" closable="true" skipDetailIfEqualsSummary="true" escape="true">
    <p:autoUpdate />
</p:messages>

<p:inputText id="inputTxt" value="#{testBacking.newValue}" required="true" requiredMessage="Cannot be blank">
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" process="@this" listener="#{testBacking.updateNewValueExists}" />
</p:inputText>

<p:datePicker id="datePicker" value="#{testBacking.newDate}" required="true" requiredMessage="Start Date Cannot be blank" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />

<p:commandButton id="cmdBtn" value="Do it" process="inputTxt,datePicker,@this" update="msgs" action="#{testBacking.pressBtn}">
    <p:confirm header="Already Exists" message="#{testBacking.newValue} already exists. Are you sure?" disabled="#{not testBacking.newValueExists}" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" responsive="true">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no ui-button-flat" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

with a backing bean of

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestBacking implements Serializable {

    private boolean newValueExists;
    private String newValue;
    private LocalDate newDate;

    public void updateNewValueExists() {
        newValueExists = newValue != null && newValue.equals("ABC");
    }

    public void pressBtn() {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Button Pressed",
                "Button has been pressed " + newValue);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

}
```

## Working Solution

I have managed to get something working but it doesn't seem the most elegant of solutions so still looking to see if there is a better way of achieving this.

So I am using client callback paraameters to call the confirm dialog if needed and if not call the actual code.

Backing bean becomes

```
    private String newValue;
    private LocalDate newDate;

    public void pressBtn() {
        if (newValue != null && newValue.equals("ABC")) {
             PrimeRequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getCallbackParams().put("exists", true);
            return;
        }
        PrimeRequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getCallbackParams().put("exists", true);
        doStuff();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Button Pressed",
                "Button has been pressed " + newValue);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
```

and view becomes

```
<p:messages id="msgs" showDetail="true" closable="true" skipDetailIfEqualsSummary="true" escape="true">
    <p:autoUpdate />
</p:messages>

<p:inputText id="inputTxt" value="#{testBacking.newValue}" required="true" requiredMessage="Cannot be blank" />

<p:datePicker id="datePicker" value="#{testBacking.newDate}" required="true" requiredMessage="Start Date Cannot be blank" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />

<p:commandButton id="cmdBtn" value="Do it" process="inputTxt,datePicker,@this" update="msgs" action="#{testBacking.pressBtn}" oncomplete="if (args.exists) PF('confirmDlg').show()" />

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" responsive="true" widgetVar="confirmDlg" header="Already Exists" message="#{testBacking.newValue} already exists. Are you sure?">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" action="#{testBacking.doStuff}" oncomplete="PF('confirmDlg').hide()"/>
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no ui-button-flat" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

- remove `p:ajax` from `inputText`
- use `oncomplete` in `commandButton` to display confirm dialog if needed
- add `action` to actually do the work and `oncomplete` to close dialog for Yes button (need to also remove `type="button"` for it to fire the action

As above, is there is a more elegant / better way of doing this?